# Adding preference screen to Widget in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-preferences

I want to know how to add preference to widget. What are the changes required in manifest file? Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Koder,

You want to create an App Widget Configuration Activity.  See the following link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring